# Ltrim on a array using array_map in Php

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to use a ltrim on a array_map to delete the left 0. It will look like this:

```
array_map('ltrim', array('023', '0002'));
```

But I don't know how to put the 0, like in the "normal" ltrim on a string

```
ltrim($toto, "0");
```

Thanks for your help!

Jean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda function:

```
$var = array_map(function($v) { return ltrim($v, '0'); }, array('023', '0002'));
var_dump($var);
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/NoTuF